# How to escape a null character in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a library that doesn't support parametrized queries, so I'm trying to write a function to emulate them like this:

```
let params = [ String "\x00'blah" ] in
Mssql.execute ~params "SELECT $1"
```

To test this, I'm sending it a string of every ASCII character, and the only two that seem to need escaping are:

- `'` - Needs to be escaped as `''`
- `\0'` - Seems like it has to be changed to `CHAR(0)`

The null character part makes my escaping function ridiculously complicated because it has to keep track of whether a string is open and if it needs to add `+`. I could write a much simpler version that converts it to something like `CODE(0)+''''+'a'+'s'+'d'` but I suspect that's going to be very inefficient when sending megabytes of data to the server. My version is also going to be crazy inefficient if I send a megabyte of null characters (not that I plan to do that, but I don't like leaving time-bombs in code).

What I'm wondering is -- Is there any other way to escape these null chars?

(Also, am I missing anything? I can't find any documentation for this since everyone seems to assume you have access to a decent T-SQL library).

EDIT: It looks like null-characters should work in T-SQL, but I'm running into a limitation of the library I'm using, where it calls FreeTDS's [`dbcmd`](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/aict/uts/software/openbsd/ports/4.6/i386/obj/freetds-0.82.20110223/freetds-0.82/doc/reference/a00261.html#gad233fe33cad8b2ab6f2eee4572086470), which assumes the string is null-terminated, and I can't seem to find any alternative function. It looks like rewriting the library I'm using to support real parameterized queries might be the only option :\

Comment: What' are you trying to do exactly? You are worried about using `null` in a `SELECT` clause because it is null-ing a string concatenation or in `WHERE` clause because of filtering? If the concatenation is a problem you can use `CONCAT` function (it will automatically replace the `null` with empty string). If you are trying  to handle the `NULL` values in a `WHERE` clause (or `JOIN`) you could handle them using `ISNULL` function for example.

Comment: @gotqn The question concerns strings containing the [ASCII NULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character, not the handling of SQL NULL values.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know your library, but I know good library for that simple sql operations. This library is have simple methods to insert, update or delete records without write SQL command. Also support Merge command. Its mean if you don't know the record is exists or not but you want to save this.
If you want to encrypt sensitive data, also have a methods for this.

Here is example;

```
crypto.SetCryptoKey("DB-TEST-CUST");
dRec cust = new dRec("dbo.customer");
cust.fields["email"] = "john.lennon@gmail.com";
cust.fields["name"] = "John Lennon";
cust.fields["description"] = "John's secret world";
cust.fields["password"] = "abc123xyz".dEncryption();  //encryption text include some special characters, but methods support this.
if (cust.Insert() >= 0)
    return "record inserted";
else
    return "record error:" + db.LastException_Message;
```

for more information library's web site : https://www.dbdll.com/Documentation